# How can I use typeahead.js with bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead

I am putting together a prototype application for a demonstration, and am using Twitter Bootstrap 3 (http://getbootstrap.com - specifically version 3.1.1). I would like to use typeahead.js (http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/ - currently version 0.10.1) to drive search suggestions.

I have seen a few examples for previous versions, but none that seem relevant to the latest versions.

What is the best way to integrate the two?

Based on the few examples I have seen, this is what I am trying to do

```
<input type="text" class="typeahead form-control input-sm" id="searchField1"/>
```

and then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#searchField1').typeahead({
    name: 'keywords',
    local: ['foo', 'bar']
  });
});
```

However, I think things have moved on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **twitter.github.io/typeahead.js** not compatible with bootstrap 3.

You can use this **Typeahead** which is compatible with twitter bootstrap 3

https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

Actually the developer migrated bootstrap 2 code in to bootstrap 3 here is the details http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/migrate-your-templates-from-twitter-bootstrap-2-x-to-twitter-bootstrap-3/

Comment: Does this mean that typeahead.js (http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) does not work with Bootstrap 3 out of the box, and I need to use an alternative?

Comment: @Vihung the **twitter.github.io/typeahead.js** not compatible with bootstrap 3 version. The link I gave you at the top is build for bootstrap 3.Actually the developer migrated bootstrap 2 code in to bootstrap 3.

Comment: @Vihung I am also facing plenty of issues with the old version in http://www.vanmaram.com/, so that I am gonna implement new version in coming week end :)

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil Could you please elaborate on what issues you are experiencing?

Comment: Could you post a complete working example using this?

Comment: Is this still accurate? it says on https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead "With Twitter Bootstrap 3 the typeahead plugin had been dropped....Twitter's typeahead don't work direct with Bootstrap 3. The DOM structure of the dropdown menu used by typeahead.js differs from the DOM structure of the Bootstrap dropdown menu."